# Get the encoding charset in R

Tags: r, gsub

I need to extract the encoding charset from a web page, 
i found that this regex syntax can do it with different tag syntax

```
(?<=([<META|<meta])(.*)charset=)([^"'>]*)
```

In general How to make this regular expression syntax works within gsub in R

Comment: Did you try to use it with `gsub()`? What exactly is the problem? What is your definition of "work" in this case? You should make a clear [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.

Comment: `stringr::str_match(rvest::html_attr(rvest::html_nodes(xml2::read_html("http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/tips/declare.html"), xpath="//meta[@http-equiv]"), "content"), "charset=(.*)")[,2]` :: Rule of Scraping #34 - When you can use proper parsing, use it.